# Gin not rendering inherited template structure

Tags: go, go-gin

componentsI have an app in which I am trying to use multiple templates derived from a base layout.

The templates load ok when the app launch but when I navigate to the app it is either:

1. Blank when I specify a template file
2. Shows only the specific content when I use the value specified in a templates "define" parameter.

base.tmpl.html

```
{{define "base"}}
<html>
    <head>
       some title
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ template "content" . }}
    </body>
    <footer>
        {{ template "footer" . }}
    </footer>
</html>
{{end}}
```

footer.tmpl.html

```
{{define "footer"}}

<h1>Footer</h1>

{{end}}
```

home.tmpl.html - This is the page I am trying to render.

```
{{ define "content" }}
<h1>test</h1>
{{ end }}
```

This is the route. When I specify "content" I get 'test' within the h1 tags but without the footer or 'some title' from the base. When I specify `home.tmpl.html` the view is blank.

There are no errors generated for either and the responses return 200 OK.

```
func GetIndex(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "content", gin.H{
        "title": "Home Page",
    })
}
```

I am loading the templates like so:

```
func main() {
    router := setupRouter()
    router.Run()
}

func setupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    router := gin.Default()
    files, err := filepath.Glob("templates/*")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tmpl := template.Must(template.New("").ParseFiles(files...))
    router.SetHTMLTemplate(tmpl)
    router.StaticFS("/static", http.Dir("static"))

    router.SetTrustedProxies([]string{"*"})
    routes.InitializeRoutes(&router.RouterGroup)
    return router
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `home.tmpl.html` works just fine, however inside that file is nothing other than a single `define` block. **The body of a `define` block will not be rendered by itself.** You must invoke a defined template with the `{{ template "<tmpl name>"}}` action, just the same like you're already doing in `base.tmpl.html`.

Comment: @mkopriva, not sure I understand. Surely if that is the case I would just end up with the same situation the next level down? Can you shown an example?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/8u6oh60bzrS (notice that executing the template by file name prints the content surrounding the define block, x on the left and y on the right = `xy`, if there was no content surrounding the block it would print an empty string, just like in your case)

Comment: Does the above code assume using standard lib or Gin?

Comment: How are you loading the templates?

Comment: @3therk1ll I may be wrong but as far as I know gin uses stdlib templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following setup resolved the issue

1. Rename `base.tmpl.html` to `base.layout.tmpl`

   ```
   {{define "base"}}
    <html>
        <head>
           some title
        </head>
        <body>
            {{block "content" .}}

            {{end}}
        </body>
        {{template "footer" .}}
    </html>
   {{end}}
   ```
2. home.tmpl.html

   ```
   {{template "base" .}}
   {{define "content"}}
       <h1>test</h1>
   {{ end }}
   ```
3. footer.tmpl.html

   ```
   {{define "footer"}}

    <footer>
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </footer>

    {{end}}
   ```